# Best way to filter objects

Tags: javascript

My object looks like this

```
const obj = Immutable.fromJS({
    {
        1: {foo: 'a'}, 2: {foo: 'b'}, 3: {foo: 'ac'}, ...
    }
 });
```

I want to search the object, and return the result like this

```
const results = {
    1: {foo: 'a'}, 3: {foo: 'ac'}
};
```

That is what I've got so far. However, this only works if `object` is an `Immutable Object`.

```
const search = 'a';
const results = obj.filter(elem => {
      return search.split(' ').some(word => {
        return (
          elem.get('foo').indexOf(word) > -1 
          )
      });
    })
```

How to filter if `obj` is a Vanilla JavaScript object?

Comment: what does this .get do? How does the search word? Does it look in the object keys? The info provided is insufficient. You return 1 and 3 in the result, what was searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Immutable Object` is a vanilla javascript type. Are you using some sort of third-party library?

### How to filter a javascript object

Regular javascript objects don't have a `filter` method defined. One way of solving the issue is to convert an object to an array of its entries first, filter the entries, and then convert back to an object:

```js
const filterObject = ( filterFn, obj ) => {
  const validEntries = Object
    .entries(obj)
    .filter(filterFn);
    
  return Object.fromEntries(validEntries);
};
  
  
console.log(
  filterObject(
    ([ key, value ]) => value !== 2,   
    { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
  )
);
```

Note that `Object.fromEntries` is not supported by all browsers yet.

You might notice that my filter function is a bit different then one you'd pass to an `Array#filter` call. `Object.entries` returns an array of key-value pairs. Therefore, the `filterFn` should take an array of key and value, which I destructure in the arguments.

### Implementing your requested filter logic

```js
const filterObject = ( filterFn, obj ) => {
  const validEntries = Object
    .entries(obj)
    .filter(filterFn);
    
  return Object.fromEntries(validEntries);
};
  
const search = "a";
const myFilter = ([_, elem]) => { // elem corresponds to our entry's value
  return search
    .split(' ')
    .some(word =>
      elem.foo.indexOf(word) > -1 // Use the regular . syntax instead of .get 
    );
}
  
console.log(
  filterObject(
    myFilter,  
    { 1: {foo: 'a'}, 2: {foo: 'b'}, 3: {foo: 'ac'} }
  )
);
```

Comment: I edited my Q. I hope its better understandable now.

Comment: I understood your question correctly, I just left it up to you to use it to reimplement your own search logic... I've now added the whole solution to the answer for you to copy-paste, or read.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to clarify that I am using `ImmutableJS`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
const keys = [1, 3];

const obj = {1: {test: 1}, 2: {test: 2}, 3: {test: 3}};

let yourObject = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => keys.includes(parseInt(key)))
    .map(key => {
        return {[key]: obj[key]}
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => Object.assign({}, a,b));
console.log(yourObject);
```